Checksum beyond my skill level - but only 4 bits
I'm trying to reverse engineer an IR protocol for laser tag guns, and the documentation I have says there should only be 14 bits, except I'm getting 24 from this particular set. The manufacturer likely modified the spec (Miles Tag 2) so their gear wouldn't play nicely with anyone else.
In looking at the received codes, the original spec for the first 14 bits of data is correct, the next 6 bits always appear to be 0, and then there are 4 bits that change according to the player, team, and damage that may be a checksum.
It's not a simple Sum, XOR, or even a XOR for a constant, and that's pretty much where my skillset ends. It may be a CRC, or even something else but I'm not knowledgeable enough to calculate this.
The spec data if it matters is that the first bit indicates it's a shot (from a tagger) or a message
The 2nd to 8th bits are the player number
The 9-10th are the team (4 teams)
the 11-14th are the damage (looked up in a table with a total of 16 values possible)
Here's a table of the received IR codes for a shot(0) from Player 9(1001) on Red Team (00) for each of the damage amounts on the left. The hex codes need to be reversed to get the original binary, so I've done that. Hyphens were added by me for readability while I tried to figure this out. The 4 bit code does change if you change the player number, team, or damage. I found through testing that Player 9 and 16 collide and have the same codes for the same damage (if both on team red) Also, Player 16, despite using a 5th bit for their player number still has the six 0 bits followed by 4 random bits.
Damage Table for Player 9 on the Red Team










1
0xE00090
00001001-00-0000-00-0000-0111


2
0x202090
00001001-00-0001-00-00000100


4
0x801090
00001001-00-0010-00-00000001


5
0x403090
00001001-00-0011-00-00000010


7
0xD00890
00001001-00-0100-00-00001011


10
0x102890
00001001-00-0101-00-00001000


15
0xB01890
00001001-00-0110-00-00001101


17
0x703890
00001001-00-0111-00-00001110


20
0x600490
00001001-00-1000-00-00000110


25
0xA02490
00001001-00-1001-00-00000101


30
0x001490
00001001-00-1010-00-00000000


35
0xC03490
00001001-00-1011-00-00000011


40
0x500C90
00001001-00-1100-00-00001010


50
0x902C90
00001001-00-1101-00-00001001


75
0x301C90
00001001-00-1110-00-00001100


100
0xF03C90
00001001-00-1111-00-00001111



Any help would be appreciated.

Can you send deliberately corrupted data at the receivers? My first guess is that the extra changing part is an error correcting code to fix single bit errors. It might be worth guessing that it is say Hamming(15,11) for a quick test. Other ECCs are available.

I did try changing the damage amount and transmitting, it did not register as a hit. I will try a single bit flip later today, since I don't remember how many bits I flipped for that test.

Confirmed flipping a single bit (in the first 14 bits) does not register as a shot.

Checksum information can be found in this document: http://hosting.cmalton.me.uk/chrism/lasertag/MT2Proto.pdf

No it can't. The only checksum information in there is in the message packets for scoring. The company (as per my note) has said they added a modified sum hash.
